# IntelliJ compile errors with RxJava fromCallable() method in Groovy app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, groovy, rx-java

I am working on a spring boot app that uses RxJava 1.0 and I am building it with the IntelliJ IDE, using the Groovy programming language.  I can't seem to get it to accept my syntax for an *Observable.fromCallable()* call, shown below.  I am using the exact syntax that I have seen in examples for the *fromCallable()* method, albeit from Java examples not Groovy, since I can't seem to find any Groovy examples.  Here's my code:

```
.doOnNext
{
    // Emit an observable that waits for the call in the closure passed to fromCallable().
    Observable.fromCallable( () -> { httpCallThatReturnsAnObservable() })
}
```

I get an error at the cursor position following the right paren *")"* in the head of the anonymous method and after the **">"** character before the body of the closure, at the locations I have placed underscores in the line below:

```
()_->_ { }
```

The first error is:

```
Expression expected. ')' or ',' expected.
```

The second error is just:

```
')' or ',' expected.
```

Note, *httpCallThatReturnsAnObservable()* returns an Observable.

I am using *fromCallable()* because of a blog post I read that indicated it is the preferred method to using rather than using the *defer()* method or using a blockable Observable.  I also have been warned by one of my colleagues not to use *defer()* in anything but a controller inside the spring boot app and the current code is *not* part of a controller.

Can someone give me the correct syntax for *fromCallable()* using Groovy?

Comment: This is a java8 lamba expression, which Groovy does not understand.  You can use a Groovy closure instead.  E.g. instead of `()-> {...}` use `{ -> ... }`

Comment: @cfrick Thanks, that worked.  Please promote your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.  I would appreciate if you added a little detail as to what happens if you put an argument on the left side of the "->" symbol, and what that means if you do.  I did not do that when I tried your solution so I'm curious as to how things change if I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE (and the Groovy compiler) are rightfully complaining about that syntax there.  This is a java8 lamba expression, which Groovy does not understand.

You have to use a Groovy closure instead or have an anon class same as with Java (e.g. like before 8).

E.g. instead of `() -> {...}` use `{ -> ... }` here.  This gives you a closure with no arguments.  Groovy will do the proper thing and "cast" that to that single method interface and you are done.

Basic rule of thumb: move the args of the lambda (what's in the `(...)`; in your case nothing) and that `->` into the `{}` and remove the `()`.